# Programs take a long time to load after startup

Tags: macos, mac, startup

After turning on my computer, logging in, and waiting for the desktop to load, I try to start a program. It takes a really long time to load, no matter which program I try. After about a minute of the icon bouncing stupidly up and down it finally opens. From then on programs start much more quickly. Why is that?

Comment: Would that be normal considering the boot process is not complete ?

Answer (score 1):

How many items are there on the desktop? How much RAM does your machine has? How much storage are you using?

If you are using lot of storage then try cleaning up your temporary files using cleanmymac or some software from mac app store. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

Your desktop loading takes to long and to many resources.

Starting a app meanwhile will be delayed till that process has completed.